# How to combine the statement for loop?

Tags: python-2.7

This is my code example:

```
list_participants = [{'Name': 'Rudi', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Age': 17},
                     {'Name': 'Ica', 'Gender': 'Female', 'Age': 18},
                     {'Name': 'Uci', 'Gender': 'Female', 'Age': 18}
                    ]

Oldest_age = 0
oldest_participant = []
male = 0
female = 0

for participant in list_participants:
  print participant
  age = participant['Age']
  if age > Oldest_age:
    Oldest_age = age

for participant in list_participants:
  name = participant['Name']
  age = participant['Age']
  if age == Oldest_age:
    oldest_participant.append(name)

for participant in list_participants:
  if participant == 'Male':
    male += 1
  elif participant == 'Female':
    female += 1
```

I want a simple for loop that is converted into one for loop. I tried it once but there was a mistake so the output did not match my wishes

Answer (score 0):

In a single iteration you could update the oldest age, and if you find age older than your current maximum, just clear the list of oldest participants:

```
oldest_age = 0
oldest_participant = []
male = 0
female = 0

for participant in list_participants:
    age = participant['Age']
    name = participant['Name']
    if age > oldest_age:
        oldest_age = age  
        del oldest_participant[:]       

    if age == oldest_age:
        oldest_participant.append(name)

    if participant == 'Male':
        male += 1
    elif participant == 'Female':
        female += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can make only one for loop to have your desired output (I corrected your male and female count too because i found you weren't counting them)

code is as follows:

```
list_participants = [{'Name': 'Rudi', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Age': 17},
                     {'Name': 'Ica', 'Gender': 'Female', 'Age': 18},
                     {'Name': 'Uci', 'Gender': 'Female', 'Age': 18}
                    ]
Oldest_age = 0
oldest_participant = []
male = 0
female = 0

for participant in list_participants:
    print participant

    age = participant['Age']
    if age > Oldest_age:
        oldest_participant = []
        Oldest_age = age

    name = participant['Name']
    age = participant['Age']
    if age == Oldest_age:
        oldest_participant.append(name)

    gender = participant['Gender']  # here this will make the count right
    if gender == 'Male':
        male += 1
    elif gender == 'Female':
        female += 1
```

and so if you test :

```
print Oldest_age
print oldest_participant
print male
print female
```

the output will be:

```
18
['Ica', 'Uci']
1
2
```

Happy Coding.